# Dependencies not injected propperly on Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I am running my code on dev mode without compiling the code using di:compile and it works well. However when I turn it in production mode and compile it running di:compile then it breaks.

I wonder why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use magento setup:di:compile on a production mode site at this time. From the devdocs website

> There is a known issue with the single-tenant compiler; it does not currently compile proxies. Therefore, if you're preparing to deploy to production, you must use the multi-tenant compiler.

You can read more about this issue here

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html#config-cli-subcommands-single